# Python sends malformed UDP Packets

Tags: python, networking, udp, wireshark

I am having trouble receiving UDP packets on an Android device, so I want to find out if I am sending them properly. Using Wireshark, everytime I try to send a UDP packet to a remote address, the following error message occurs:

```
232646  311.898009000   172.56.16.78    192.168.0.3 UDP 64  Source port: 31947  Destination port: 5001 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]
Frame check sequence: 0xf5b6d06d [incorrect, should be 0xb0c869e3]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Would this be the cause of why I could not receive UDP packets on my Android device?

Server Code:

```
import http.server
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

class ThreadedUDPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip().decode("utf-8")
        print("{} Recieved: ".format(self.client_address) + data)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        response = data.upper()
        sock.sendto(bytes(response, "utf-8"), self.client_address)
        print("{} Sent: {}".format(self.client_address,response))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    udpserver = ThreadedUDPServer((HOST,PORT+1), ThreadedUDPRequestHandler)
    udp_thread = threading.Thread(target=udpserver.serve_forever)
    udp_thread.daemon = True
    udp_thread.start()
    print("UDP serving at port", PORT+1)
    while True:
        pass
    udpserver.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're sending packets using regular userspace sockets. In that case, there's very little chance that the packets are being sent malformed since the FCS is generated physically by the network interface card.

What you're probably seeing is an FCS error [due to completely different reasons](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/22483/ethernet-frame-check-sequence-incorrect), which can be safely disregarded.

I'd look for other reasons for why the other device doesn't receive the packet, like firewalls or NAT. Start by using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or a similar tool for sending and receiving the UDP packets between the two machines.

Comment: I've asked in another question about UDP port forwarding to overcome blocking NATs and why Android would not receive UDP packets. I sent packets UDP packets both from my Server, and the Android client towards each other, but only the Android-to-Server packets make it through, and not the Server-to-Android ones. Would you mind trying to help me on that problem?

Comment: Sure. I posted a comment there, pointing to a relevant answer I wrote for someone else. Hope it helps.